# Flume - sink as Maprfs. Files not writing

Tags: hdfs, flume

My source type is spooldir and sink type is hdfs. There is no error but files are not copied.

Between I am completely aware of the NFS mount feature to copy data. I am in learning flume and I want to try this feature. Once this is working I would like try to write data using log4j, avro as source and hdfs as sink.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Regards
Mani

```js
# Name the components of this agents
maprfs-agent.sources = spool-collect
maprfs-agent.sinks = maprfs-write
maprfs-agent.channels = memory-channel

# Describe/ Configure the sources
maprfs-agent.sources.spool-collect.type = spooldir
maprfs-agent.sources.spool-collect.spoolDir = /home/appdata/mani
maprfs-agent.sources.spool-collect.fileHeader = true
maprfs-agent.sources.spool-collect.bufferMaxLineLength = 500
maprfs-agent.sources.spool-collect.bufferMaxLines = 10000
maprfs-agent.sources.spool-collect.batchSize = 100000

# Describe/ Configure sink
maprfs-agent.sinks.maprfs-write.type = hdfs
maprfs-agent.sinks.maprfs-write.hdfs.fileType  = DataStream
maprfs-agent.sinks.maprfs-write.hdfs.path = maprfs:///sample.node.com/user/hive/test
maprfs-agent.sinks.maprfs-write.writeFormat = Text
maprfs-agent.sinks.maprfs-write.hdfs.proxyUser = root
maprfs-agent.sinks.maprfs-write.hdfs.kerberosPrincipal = mapr
maprfs-agent.sinks.maprfs-write.hdfs.kerberosKeytab = /opt/mapr/conf/flume.keytab
maprfs-agent.sinks.maprfs-write.hdfs.filePrefix = %{file}
maprfs-agent.sinks.maprfs-write.hdfs.fileSuffix = .csv
maprfs-agent.sinks.maprfs-write.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
maprfs-agent.sinks.maprfs-write.hdfs.rollCount = 0
maprfs-agent.sinks.maprfs-write.hdfs.rollSize = 0
maprfs-agent.sinks.maprfs-write.hdfs.batchSize = 100
maprfs-agent.sinks.maprfs-write.hdfs.idleTimeout = 0
maprfs-agent.sinks.maprfs-write.hdfs.maxOpenFiles = 5


# Configure channel buffer
maprfs-agent.channels.memory-channel.type = memory
maprfs-agent.channels.memory-channel.capacity = 1000

# Bind the source and the sink to the channel
maprfs-agent.sources.spool-collect.channels = memory-channel
maprfs-agent.sinks.maprfs-write.channel = memory-channel
```

I am getting below message. no error and no files copied when I execute below command.

hadoop mfs -ls /user/hive/test

```js
15/05/26 13:55:45 INFO node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Configuration provider starting
15/05/26 13:55:45 INFO node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Reloading configuration file:mapr-spool.conf
15/05/26 13:55:45 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Added sinks: maprfs-write Agent: maprfs-agent
15/05/26 13:55:45 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:maprfs-write
15/05/26 13:55:45 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [maprfs-agent]
15/05/26 13:55:45 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Creating channels
15/05/26 13:55:45 INFO channel.DefaultChannelFactory: Creating instance of channel memory-channel type memory
15/05/26 13:55:45 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Created channel memory-channel
15/05/26 13:55:45 INFO source.DefaultSourceFactory: Creating instance of source spool-collect, type spooldir
15/05/26 13:55:45 INFO sink.DefaultSinkFactory: Creating instance of sink: maprfs-write, type: hdfs
15/05/26 13:55:47 INFO hdfs.HDFSEventSink: Hadoop Security enabled: false
15/05/26 13:55:47 INFO hdfs.HDFSEventSink: Auth method: PROXY
15/05/26 13:55:47 INFO hdfs.HDFSEventSink:  User name: root
15/05/26 13:55:47 INFO hdfs.HDFSEventSink:  Using keytab: false
15/05/26 13:55:47 INFO hdfs.HDFSEventSink:  Superuser auth: SIMPLE
15/05/26 13:55:47 INFO hdfs.HDFSEventSink:  Superuser name: root
15/05/26 13:55:47 INFO hdfs.HDFSEventSink:  Superuser using keytab: false
15/05/26 13:55:47 INFO hdfs.HDFSEventSink: Logged in as user root
15/05/26 13:55:47 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Channel memory-channel connected to [spool-collect, maprfs-write]
15/05/26 13:55:47 INFO node.Application: Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{spool-collect=EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:Spool Directory source spool-collect: { spoolDir: /home/appdata/mani } }} sinkRunners:{maprfs-write=SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@7fc7efa0 counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } }} channels:{memory-channel=org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel{name: memory-channel}} }
15/05/26 13:55:47 INFO node.Application: Starting Channel memory-channel
15/05/26 13:55:47 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitored counter group for type: CHANNEL, name: memory-channel: Successfully registered new MBean.
15/05/26 13:55:47 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: CHANNEL, name: memory-channel started
15/05/26 13:55:47 INFO node.Application: Starting Sink maprfs-write
15/05/26 13:55:47 INFO node.Application: Starting Source spool-collect
15/05/26 13:55:47 INFO source.SpoolDirectorySource: SpoolDirectorySource source starting with directory: /home/appdata/mani
15/05/26 13:55:47 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitored counter group for type: SINK, name: maprfs-write: Successfully registered new MBean.
15/05/26 13:55:47 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: SINK, name: maprfs-write started
15/05/26 13:55:47 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitored counter group for type: SOURCE, name: spool-collect: Successfully registered new MBean.
15/05/26 13:55:47 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: SOURCE, name: spool-collect started
15/05/26 13:55:47 INFO avro.ReliableSpoolingFileEventReader: Preparing to move file /home/appdata/mani/cron-s3.log to /home/appdata/mani/cron-s3.log.COMPLETED
15/05/26 13:55:47 INFO hdfs.HDFSDataStream: Serializer = TEXT, UseRawLocalFileSystem = false
15/05/26 13:55:48 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Creating maprfs:///sample.node.com/user/hive/test/.1432644947885.csv.tmp
15/05/26 13:57:08 INFO avro.ReliableSpoolingFileEventReader: Preparing to move file /home/appdata/mani/network-usage.log to /home/appdata/mani/network-usage.log.COMPLETED
15/05/26 13:57:08 INFO avro.ReliableSpoolingFileEventReader: Preparing to move file /home/appdata/mani/processor-usage-2014-10-17.log to /home/appdata/mani/processor-usage-2014-10-17.log.COMPLETED
15/05/26 13:57:25 INFO avro.ReliableSpoolingFileEventReader: Preparing to move file /home/appdata/mani/total-processor-usage.log to /home/appdata/mani/total-processor-usage.log.COMPLETED
15/05/26 13:57:25 INFO source.SpoolDirectorySource: Spooling Directory Source runner has shutdown.
15/05/26 13:57:26 INFO source.SpoolDirectorySource: Spooling Directory Source runner has shutdown.
15/05/26 13:57:26 INFO source.SpoolDirectorySource: Spooling Directory Source runner has shutdown.
15/05/26 13:57:27 INFO source.SpoolDirectorySource: Spooling Directory Source runner has shutdown.
15/05/26 13:57:27 INFO source.SpoolDirectorySource: Spooling Directory Source runner has shutdown.
15/05/26 13:57:28 INFO source.SpoolDirectorySource: Spooling Directory Source runner has shutdown.
```